# Wordpress Query - Get Posts In BOTH (2) Categories

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Actually, what I have is this:

CATEGORY1 
-Subcat1 
-Subcat2

CATEGORY2 
-Subcat3 
-Subcat4

Subcats of course being the child categories of their parent categories.

What I need is to get the posts that belong to **Subcat1** of CATEGORY1 **'AND'** (means that I need both conditions to be true) posts that belong to **ANY of the Subcats** of CATEGORY2.

I tried this, but it doesn't work unless the user ticks both the parent category and the subcategory when assigning a post:

```
$query = new WP_Query(array("post_type" => "XYZ", "category__and" => array(CATEGORY1->Subcat1,CATEGORY2), "posts_per_page"=>-1));
```

Sidenote: CATEGORY1->Subcat1 is a variable that was previously defined in the code, but I just wrote it this way for the sake of demonstrating the query. All the arguments of the array are corresponding IDs.

Comment: You can specify multiple categories, i.e. 1,2,3,4 for `'category' => 1,2,3,4`

Comment: Wouldn't that return posts that belong in any of those categories?

Answer (score 0):

WP_query treats subcategories as categories of their own. So, you could easily  use `$query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=Subcat1,Subcat3,Subcat4' );`

Check [WP_query Categories parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters)

Comment: yeah but this would give me posts that are in any of those subcats, right?

Comment: It  would give you posts in the specified subcategories **ONLY**.

Answer (score 0):

If the condition is a post to be tagged by both categories, you can concatenate categories rather than list them in the argument var.

'category_name'    => 'News+Featured'

instead of

'category_name'    => 'News,Featured'

That way the result will return posts only when both categories are checked for a post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `+` instead of `,` in WP_Query:

```php
WP_Query(array("category_name" => " Subcat1+CATEGORY2 "));
```